# How to show x-axis values on top and bottom at the same time in a horizontal bar chart

Tags: ng-apexcharts

I have a horizontal bar chart that is very long, so the user has to scroll to the bottom to see the values on the x-axis. I know about the `position?: string;` property of the `ApexXAxis` type, but looking at [the documentation](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/xaxis/#position), it only allows the values "top" and "bottom". Is it possible to show it on both positions at the same time?